# Conditional probability of points in a plane

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I've ran into a problem with a project of mine and it boils down to the following example. Suppose I've a number of points dispersed in the region defined by $[0,100]\times[0,100]$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The region is allowed to "wrap around" on itself, so a point at coordinate $(0,57)$ is distance $1$ from a point at coordinate $(100,56)$. The number of points is immaterial, but for the sake of clarity let's say there are $1000$ points. Note that the points need not have integer coordinates. Each point is given a color, so there are $500$ blue points and $500$ red points. **What is the probability that, given a blue point, there is a red point within distance $\varepsilon$ of the blue point?**

Comment: The only blue point that matters is the blue point that we are given.  Ignore the remaining $499$ blue points.  Now, the total area of the region is $100^2$.  The area of the target area is $\pi\epsilon^2$ (*conveniently true regardless where our blue point is since the region wraps around on itself*).  The probability of a particular red point being within that target region is then $\frac{\pi\epsilon^2}{100^2}$ (*by assumption of what it means to disperse the points randomly in the region*).  Now, apply binomial distribution and conclude.

Comment: @JMoravitz You should write your comment as an answer.

Comment: @JMoravitz So the probability is $\pi\varepsilon^2/100^2$... It seems I was over complicating things. But why then would I apply binomial distribution, if I've already arrived at my probability?

Comment: You misunderstand.  That is the probability that if you have *one* red point and one blue point that the red point is within the target distance of the blue.  Two red points and one blue, it will be more likely than that, yes?  With $n$ independent trials of an experiment, each with probability $p$ of success, the probability of at least one success would be $1-(1-p)^n$.  Replace here $p$ by $\frac{\pi\epsilon^2}{100^2}$ and $n$ by $500$

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah, I see! Thank you so much for your help!